# How to add flask cor module to work on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, cors

I have a problem when I try to use flask_cors in my flask app but when I deploy this app on Heroku so it fails and from the Heroku logs I have this error :

`from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin 
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'`
I have added 'flask_cors' in the requirement.txt file but it's still no work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run pip install when deploying? 'requirements.txt' just specify the dependencies of current project and you need to install them.

Make sure you have the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command before start the flask app.